# How to extend a plugin in django cms

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I using plugin 'Djangocms-blog' and I want to add some extra things (ie. favourites ranking etc).

How can I implement those features to existing plugin? I need to fork project and then add some fields to model or in django-cms it's possible to extends plugin to another and how can I do it? Thanks for good answers and links to tutorials ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend an application that you install via pip is quite straightforward.

For what you'd like to do the easiest thing to do would be to simply add a full copy of the application to your project's root directory and then Django will load it from there instead of `site-packages`.

You can also override templates from installed apps, for example, by mimicking the template path of something loaded from `site-packages` the `.html` file in your project's template directory will get loaded instead of that in the python path.

So to extend an application's features, model attributes etc you'd just make whatever changes you wanted in the copy of the application in your project. Alternatively you could create your own application & inherit the parts of `Djangocms-blog` that suit your project while extending it to do what your application needs.

Comment: It looks nice, but how to extend anything?

Comment: Be more specific. Extending `things` isn't generic.

Comment: Ok sorry, I just want to: 1) add new field "Favourites" and then create list of most favourites articles. 2) add comments to articles (create by myself) or using another plugin with comments ;)

Comment: Well just like I said then, create a copy of the application in your project, and modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: Like i thought :) Btw. Do you know good plugin with comments to easy connecting with `Djangocms-blog` :)?

Comment: It doesn't work for me :/ I have errors. I will fight with it and maybe I'll create task on stackoverflow with mentioning you;) Btw. really thank you for helping ;)

Comment: @markwalker_ I know it is frown upon thing here, but thank you so much for the answer! You're the best!